# inserting text to file

Tags: python, file, text, insert

I want to insert some text to my file,

```
X
---
0.1
0.2
 .
 .
 .
99.9
```

I want to add to that file some random float numbers:

```
 X     Y   
0.1 ,38.58
0.2 ,12.45
0.3 ,79.03
.  ,  .
.  ,  .
99.9 ,47.36
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import random

a=[random.uniform(10,100) for i in range (1000)]

c = open("dosya.txt","w")
c.write('X DEGER:  Y DEGER:\n')
c.write('--------------\n')

count = 0
while (count < 99.9):
    count = count + 0.1
    c.write("%s \n" % (count,))    
    c.close

c= open("dosya.txt","r+")
c.seek(37,0)
for k in range(900):
    print a[k] 
    c.write(",%f" %(a[k]))

    c.seek(5,1)    
c.close
```

When I run that, I got messy text file.. Could you tell me where is my fault?

Answer (score 2):

You did not close the file. You only referenced the method, instead of actually calling it. Compare:

```
c.close
```

To

```
c.close()
```

Thus, your file will only write everything in the second for-loop. And even here, things will get messy. (hence why you get a "messy text file").

---

It is actually more pythonic to use the `with` statement here to open files. It has a great advantage that it will automatically close files once you are finished working with them, so you don't need to call `close()`:

```
with open("dosya.txt","w") as c:
    c.write('X DEGER:  Y DEGER:\n')
    c.write('--------------\n')

    count = 0
    while (count < 99.9):
        count = count + 0.1
        c.write("%s" % (count,))
```

---

Your code is also a bit... odd. I'll address some issues:

`c.write("%s \n" % (count,))`. There is no need for the extra comma here. You can just remove it. So your code should look like:

```
count = 0
while count < 99.9:
    count += 0.1
    f.write('%s, \n' % count)
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? `(count,)` What are you trying to achieve by it? If you want parentheses around the number just put it into the string: `c.write("(%s) \n" % count)` Also, `count = count + 0.1` can be written as `count += 0.1`

Comment: @InbarRose I addressed the main problem. But I'll edit my answer

Comment: the extra comma doesn't make a difference: `(1,2,) == (1,2) => true`

Comment: @tenstar That's why I said there was no need for it :p.

Answer (score 0):

instead of just referring  to the method, you must call it.

try this instead:

`c.close()`

you mistyped it as:

`c.close`

Comment: there is no difference between mine and what u saying i tried both

Comment: can u tell what does ur text file look like?

Comment: .1,15.957096
0.2 ,17.7646010.3  ,16.634242.4   ,36.2960095    ,75.380792     ,41.399928     ,25.812779     ,52.503987     ,66.059277     ,61.988461     ,58.586576    
,18.795600   
1,67.372559  
1.,57.688011 
1.6,21.963218
1.7 ,11.2010241.8  ,73.002422.9   ,26.4042970    ,32.556507     ,68.669588     ,27.923578     ,21.795854     ,58.223057     ,64.326399     ,58.302718    
,61.212347   
2,65.266870  
3.,60.669146

Comment: they must be  like but they are unsencronized 0.1, 15.95

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are trying to write a file with 2 columns of data in 2 passes.

Instead, do it in one pass:

```
import random

with open('dosya.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('X DEGER:  Y DEGER:\n')
    f.write('--------------\n')
    count = 0.0
    while (count < 99.9):
        count += 0.1
        f.write('%s, %f\n' % (count, random.uniform(10,100))
```